# Custom UI Button setTitle(_:for:) method not working

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a custom UI Button subclass and when I call the `setTitle(_:for:)` method, the title is not changing and the button displays "Button" title. I call this method in `awakeFromNib()`.

This is my custom button code

```
class DeleteButton: UIButton {

  override func awakeFromNib() {
    self.backgroundColor = .systemRed
    self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    self.setTitle("Eliminar", for: .normal)
  }

  override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.height/2
  }
}
```

Debugging the code I get this:

[image: code from debug]

So I don't understand why the button doesn't show the title in the UI. Is something about the `awakeFromNib()`?

Comment: How are you initializing your button? Not sure what is the relation between your label and your button.

Comment: @LeoDabus via Storyboard. The self.titleLabel is the button title label. I don't understand why the `self.titleLabel.text` returns "Button" but the `self.title(for: .normal)` returns the right title.

Comment: You are also setting two other things - backgroundColor and titleColor. Since you are using a Storyboard, what happens if you set this button to systemBlue there? Is it blue or red? (Easiest way to eliminate things.)

Comment: titleLabel.text says what is the current value of that label's text. But UIButtons have states, and you configure titles for those different states, which means when the button changes states it changes the text in its own label. That hasn't happened yet

Answer (score 1):

The issue was solved. I missed the `super.layoutSubviews()` in the `layoutSubviews()` method

Answer (score 0):

Instead of set value in `awakeFromNib()`, you can set the value inside an init function. For example, you can `override init(frame: CGRect)`

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        self.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        self.setTitle("Eliminar", for: .normal)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your Button's subclass into DeleteButton

[image]

Comment: Welcome, @Danny_Chan! Would you be willing to provide more detail or explain how you arrived at that answer? I believe it would be useful to those reading your post (:

Comment: It's already declared as my button's subclass called DeleteButton.

Answer (score 0):

I CHANGED "TITLE" PROPERTY FROM "Attributed" to "Plain". And it worked for me.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBMQd.jpg)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case  if the button type is system, then it works, no idea why :(

UIButton(type: .system)

in iOS 17.2